# Is there a way to access and retrieve iCloud reminders with Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, api, icloud, reminders

My goal is to build a task dashboard app which will pull tasks from different systems (e.g. Basecamp, Apple Reminders, ...) and display them in a certain way to a user. My biggest question so far whether there is any way how to access Apple Reminders with web application. I know it is possible via iOS app or OSX app.
I guess I have to connect directly to Apple iCloud servers but haven't found any meaningful answer or hint how to do that.

Answer (score 10):

Check this gem https://github.com/adammck/ruby-icloud. It's supposed to be an iCloud api in Ruby but it just supports reminders for now. So, you are a lucky guy ;)

Answer (score -6):

Tomas, if it's useful, we just released iCloud/iOS Reminders support in Taco. It already supports Basecamp, Basecamp Classic, Highrise, and about 40 other services: https://tacoapp.com/. There's also a Chrome extension so you can see your iCloud reminders on new Chrome tabs.

Comment: I'm glad you have an app, but as a developer that doesn't help me very much. Since it's cloud-hosted, I can't customize the amount of data that gets imported from the various services easily, and I'd have no control over another user interface representation of what might essentially be called a multi-cloud-synced list of to do items. It's cool, but not necessarily appropriate for a StackOverflow answer to a programming question.

Comment: I disagree - by definition, since I replied :) Those considerations are real (and reasons for https://tacoapp.com/info/privacy), but my reply was for the OP's situation: "a task dashboard app which will pull tasks from different systems."

If he'd written "I want to pull iCloud Reminders in order to put them into my Exchange system," or any of a thousand other reasons for wanting to do so, it wouldn't be relevant. Of the things I've created, if you'd told me "Something like what you want already exists," I'd have cared. That my reply doesn't cover every case doesn't make it inappropriate.

Comment: It is still supported in Taco? I do not see iCloud mentioned on the website.